# How many subchapters in the Zohar Hakadosh?

Tags: zohar, statistics

How many subchapters are in the Zohar, including the Tikkunei Zohar and the Zohar CHadash?

I am trying to make a schedule.

Comment: Define "subchapter." I've only seen Zohars printed by volume and page, not subchapter.

Comment: There is a schedule that follows the weekly Torah portion in most Sulam editions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In accord with @DonielF's question, I am not sure what is meant by subchapter.  I don't study Zohar, but I will go with how it is divided on Sefaria.

The Zohar itself has 3 volumes.  They have 251, 267, and 299 pages respectively.  Volumes 2 & 3 end one page later than this number as they have no page 1, but volume 1 has a page 1.  That amounts to 817 pages.  These are divided both into volumes and into parshiyot.  The first volume covers parshiyot of Sefer Bereishit.  The second volume covers parshiyot of Sefer Shemot.  The third volume covers the remaining three sefarim of Chumash.

Tikkunei Zohar has 149 pages.

Zohar HaChadash has entries on 20 of the parshiyot of Chumash, plus 9 additional sections.